# Fetching fields with specific criteria - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to extract particular data from 2 tables based on specific criteria. But the result is not as expected. Can someone please help?

**Criteria**:
Need to fetch id pairs whose type is **A** alone.

**Tables**:

Table A

```
ID1                 ID2
579643307310619501   644543316683180704
296151129721950503   328945291791563504
```

Table B

```
ID                 TYPE
579643307310619501   A
579643307310619501   B
579643307310619501   C
644543316683180704   A
296151129721950503   A
328945291791563504   A
```

**Expected Result**:

```
ID1                 ID2
296151129721950503  328945291791563504
```

(Since only this pair is of type A alone, individually)

**Note**: The IDs, ID1 and ID2 both must be present in ID field of Table B.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT  id1, id2 
FROM  A
JOIN  B ON A.id1 = B.id
WHERE A.id1 IN (SELECT id FROM B)
  AND A.id2 IN  (SELECT id FROM B)
  AND B.type='A'
GROUP BY id1, id2
HAVING count(*)=1;
```

Comment: It isn't clear why `296...` is being paired with `328...`.  Put another way, what is the logic by which you report pairs, and what determines which left side ID gets paired with which right side ID?

Comment: The IDs represent customer ID, Tim. They are linked to denote that the two customers could be the same customers.(i.e) the two paired IDs are suspected customer IDs.

Comment: I now need those suspect pairs whose individual type is A alone. Hope I am clear now :)

Comment: Clear.  I was making the problem more complicated than it is.  You already have the pairs in the A table, you just need to filter off records which don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the approach below, I use a CTE to first identify all `ID` values having exclusively the `'A'` type.  Then I join `TableA` to this CTE, *twice*, to filter off any records either of whose `ID1` or `ID2` values are not in the exclusively `'A'` type list.

```
WITH cte (ID) AS (
    SELECT ID
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE <> 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)

SELECT a.ID1, a.ID2
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN cte t1
    ON a.ID1 = t1.ID
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON a.ID2 = t2.ID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo]

Find below a working demo (for SQL Server - I can't get Oracle to work anywhere).

### Demo

Comment: A select without from-clause is not valid in Oracle. So "select 1" will raise a "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" error. There is a table called "dual" that returns exactly one row and that one uses in such situations: "select 1 from dual". Here is your demo with Oracle.

Comment: @miracle173 I believe my code is correct, and you should have no trouble getting it to work on Oracle developer.

Comment: @miracle173 - I have run Tim's code in SQL Fiddle against Oracle and it works.

Comment: @APC Yes, the code posted here runs in Oracle, too. But  I am talking about his Demo on http://rextester.com.This creates test data using select statements without a from-clause.

Comment: @miracle173 Hence I avoid setting up Oracle demos on rextester.  Anyway, my answer should run on Oracle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am talking about the code of your demo at http://rextester.com . you write " I can't get Oracle to work anywhere" and it will not run on Oracle Developer too for the reasons I give in my previous post.

Comment: @miracle173 Here is APC's Fiddle demo working with my query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abbd6/4

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Oracle solution using the MINUS operator.

The top sub-query gets the set of records where both ID1 and ID2 are of type `'A'`. The bottom sub-query gets the set of records where either ID1 or ID2 is not of type `'A'`. The result is the set of records in the top set which are not also in the bottom set.

```
select a.id1, a.id2
from a
     join b b1 on b1.id = a.id1
     join b b2 on b2.id = a.id2
where b1.type = 'A'
and   b2.type = 'A'    
minus
select a.id1, a.id2
from a
     join b b1 on b1.id = a.id1
     join b b2 on b2.id = a.id2
where b1.type != 'A'
or   b2.type != 'A'    
/
```

This [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20c9c/3) returns the right row but there's a bit of a problem with its display: for some reason the numbers are rounded down.

---

Note on performance

This hits table `A` twice and table `B` four times. With small tables and a well-sized buffer cache this is not so important.

@TimBiegeleisen uses the WITH clause and that approach only hits each table once. However, Oracle will materialize the CTE as a temporary table. The overhead of doing this for such small amounts of data makes his solution consistently slower than mine. Including an `/*+ inline */` hint in the CTE projection prevents Oracle from materializing the temporary table and the performance of the two queries becomes comparable.

However, if the tables become large enough there will be a point at which the WITH clause approach with a materialized temporary table is the more performative approach. As always with query tuning, the specifics matter greatly and benchmarking is the key to success.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample for Oracle and my solution.

This is valid for any letter, A, B, C... If you want only for A, add an additional filter in the where of the main query.

```
create table a (id1 number,id2 number, constraint pk_a primary key(id1,id2));
create table b (id number, type char(1), constraint pk_b primary key(id,type));

insert into a values(57,64);
insert into a values(29,32);
insert into b values(57,'A');
insert into b values(57,'B');
insert into b values(57,'C');
insert into b values(64,'A');
insert into b values(29,'A');
insert into b values(32,'A');
commit;

select a.*
 from a, b b1, b b2
 where a.id1 = b1.id
   and a.id2 = b2.id
   and b1.type = b2.type
   and not exists (select null
                     from b b1bis
                    where b1bis.id = b1.id
                      and b1.type <> b1bis.type)
   and not exists (select null
                     from b b2bis
                    where b2bis.id = b2.id
                      and b2.type <> b2bis.type);
```